C++ main thread polling and blocking, termination on signal
I have a main thread which should do some work every N seconds (20 in this case) and wait/block/suspend in-between. However, at the same time, I want the application to stop correctly on a SIGTERM/SIGINT to stay responsible.
The current idea I have is this: https://godbolt.org/z/73rsnqozW
std::binary_semaphore P_SEM{0};

void signal_handler(int signal) {
  P_SEM.release();
}

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {

    std::atomic<bool> shutdown(false);
    std::mutex cv_m;
    std::condition_variable cv;

    std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    std::signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    
    auto termination_handler = [&shutdown, &cv]() {
        P_SEM.acquire();
        shutdown.store(true);
        cv.notify_all();
    };

    auto t_termination_handler = std::async(std::launch::async, termination_handler);

    do {
        //work polling-loop
        //do work here every 20 seconds
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        cv.wait_for(lk, 20s);
    } while(!shutdown);
    return 0;
}

Is this 1) correct and 2) too complicated? I'm unsure, what exactly I can safely do in the signal handler, I know that the semaphore release should be safe.
Cheers and thanks

It is safe to call std::abort in the signal handler. Is that not good enough to stop the application?

std::abort is pretty unclean IMHO , if I recall correctly, the exit code will indicate error and also I don't get destructor calls, so any RAII protected resource (opened files, etc.) might get corrupted. But maybe it's an option in this case, given these boundary conditions.
